# How can I code exp(x) in c?

Tags: c, recursion, exp

There is a serie for the exp function whitch looks like this:
`exp(x) = (x^0)/0! + (x^1)/1! + (x^2)/2! + (x^3)/3! + ···`. And I'm trying to compute it for different values of x, checking my results with a calculator and I found that for big values, 20 for example, my results stop increasing and get stuck in a value that is almost the real one. I get `485165184.00` and the real value is `485165195.4`.

I must do this code in a for cycle or a recursive function, since it is a homework assignment.

My code looks as following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 13
#define xi 3

double fun7(int n, int m){
    int i;
    double res=1, aux=0;
    for(i=1, aux=1; i<(n+1); i++){
    res += aux;
    aux *= m;
    aux /= i;
    }
    return res-1;
}



int main() {
    int a, b, pot, x[xi];
    float R[N][xi];

    x[0] = 5;
    x[1] = 10;
    x[2] = 20;

    for(b=0; b<xi; b++){
        for (a=0, pot=1; a<N; a++){
            R[a][b] = fun7(pot, x[b]);
            pot *= 2;
        }
    }

    for(b=0; b<xi; b++){
        for (a=0, pot=1; a<N; a++){
            printf("%d\t%f\n", pot, R[a][b]);
            pot *= 2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you try casting it as a long double?

Comment: `float` --> `double`

Comment: There are ways to calculate e(x) without going through factorials... check wikipedia, google ....

Comment: "it is a homework assignment": shouldn't you have more explicit identifiers?

Comment: "checking my results with a calculator " --> better to have code check against `exp()`.

Comment: Why `double res = 1; ... for (...) { ...res += aux; ...  } return res - 1;`?  Simplify: `double res = 0; ... for (...) { ...res += aux; ...  } return res;`

Comment: @chux, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Perhaps even `double res=1, aux=1;
    for(i=1; i<= n; i++){
    aux *= m;
    aux /= i;
    res += aux;
    }
    return res;`?

Comment: @chux the series start at 1, and if i did it that way it would start on x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `float` data type can normally represent numbers with a tad more than 7 decimal digits of precision.

485165184 has 9 decimal digits. The last two digits are just meaningless noise as far as `float` goes. You really should be showing 4.851652e8, which is the correct value for exp(20) with the given level of precision.

If you want to increase precision, try using `double` or `long double` data types.

Comment: Besides, probably he's making stuff worse than it could be by summing the terms in the wrong order. When you sum series you have to start from the smallest terms, otherwise they are going to be ignored when summed with a partial sum big enough not to have enough mantissa for them.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Agree about summing terms, yet with `exp()` there is the additional challenge the smallest terms not only at one end of the series, but at both ends.

Comment: thank @n.m. I changed my array type to double from float, and that fixed my problem.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I coded this up using all the terms from the first (1.0) until a term < 1e-17.  Then added in different orders, including the smallest to largest, L to R and R to L.  I did find using smallest to largest gave the best answer, but average (0.04) and worst case (50) ULP differences indicated only a modest, maybe 20% improvement yet at a not so insignificant computation/space cost.  So at least for `exp()`, better use other techniques to improve than trying to improve via addition order.  IMO, the lest ot greatest is more valuable in series with alternating signs.